# Why Dimensions.get('window').height returns 0 on iOS?

Tags: react-native, platform

for iOS:
Dimensions.get('window').height = 0

but Dimensions.get('screen').height = something

Why it can be?

```js
console.log('DIMENSIONS', Dimensions.get('window'), Dimensions.get('screen'));


// logs
window = {fontScale: 1, height: 0, width: 0, scale: 2} 
screen = {fontScale: 1, height: 896, width: 414, scale: 2}
```

Comment: Because there is no window?

Comment: what?.................

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. It's problem in `AppDelegate.m` with RNSplashScreen.

https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#third-stepplugin-configuration

problem code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [RNSplashScreen show]; // here

    // ...other code
    return YES;
}
```

worked:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...other code

    [RNSplashScreen show];  // here
    // or
    //[RNSplashScreen showSplash:@"LaunchScreen" inRootView:rootView];
    return YES;
}
```